# How to produce UTF8 info file with makeinfo on osx?

Tags: osx, utf-8

In the texi file I have the directive `@documentencoding UTF-8` but makeinfo gives me a warning: unrecognized encoding name `UTF-8'

```
raoul@MacBook-Pro-de-Raoul oef-mode % makeinfo oef-mode.texi
oef-mode.texi:6: avertissement: nom d'encodage non reconnu « UTF-8 ».
```

```
raoul@MacBook-Pro-de-Raoul oef-mode % whereis makeinfo 
/usr/bin/makeinfo
```

```
raoul@MacBook-Pro-de-Raoul oef-mode % makeinfo --version    
makeinfo (GNU texinfo) 4.8
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to:

1. Install makeinfo with homebrew

```
raoul@MacBook-Pro-de-Raoul oef-mode % brew install texinfo
raoul@MacBook-Pro-de-Raoul oef-mode % brew info texinfo
texinfo: stable 6.7 (bottled) [keg-only]
```

As explained during installation, texinfo is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

2. So you need to have texinfo first in your PATH with this command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

3. Don't use eshell but the Terminal or shell in emacs.